# How to horizontally center AngularJs ng-Grid checkbook colum

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-grid

I am new to Angular Js and I am creating a Grid using Angular Js ng-Grid, it has a column with check-boxes but those are aligned to left, 
if anyone can explain me how to align them to center would be appreciate.

here is controller's grid code

```
$scope.currencyGrid = {
            data: 'gridDisplayObjectList',
            multiSelect: false,
            selectedItems: $scope.selectedRow,
            enableColumnResize: false,
            enableRowSelection: true,
            columnDefs: [
                  {
                      field:'IsSelect',
                      displayName: 'Select',
                      cellTemplate: '<div><input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.entity.IsSelect" ng-checked="row.IsSelect""></div>'
                  }
            ]
        };
```

[image]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you using bootstrap frame work? If so try  tag for the check box it will align center

Comment: can you explain how to use do it please?

Comment: Im not using boostrap, is there another way to do it?